# Conditional expectations and Markov processes

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Let $(X_t: t \geq 0)$ be a (real-valued) Markov process, and let $P^x$ denote the law of $X$ started from $x$, with corresponding expectation $E^x$.  Is the following identity true?

$$E(Y|X_t) = E^x(Y) \bigg\vert_{x=X_t}$$

(where $E:= E^0$, and $Y$ is a random variable that is $\sigma(X_s)$-measurable for some $s>t$).

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, but what does the notation mean in the right-hand side of the main equation?

Comment: you calculate the expectation of $Y$ under the law starting from $x$; this will give an expression in terms of $x$. You then substitute $X_t$ for $x$ into this expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $Y$ is $\sigma(X_s)$-measurable, there is a Borel function $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $Y=g(X_s)$. You then have (by the simple Markov property)
$$
E(Y|X_t) = E^x(g(X_{s-t}))\Big|_{x=X_t}.
$$